# How to split string in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
"1 chocolate bar at 25"
```

and I want to split this string into:

```
 [1, "chocolate bar", 25]
```

I don't know how to write a regex for this split. And I wanted to know whether there are any other functions to accomplish it.

Comment: What are the rules?

Comment: The format of string will be no_of_item item_name at price

Comment: Is the word `'at'` in every string?

Comment: yes 'at' will be everything. That's why i thought a regex can be generated

Comment: Try `string.match(/(\d+) +(\D+) +at +(\d+)/).captures`

Comment: Its working.. Thanks a ton @revo

Comment: Why do you assume a regex is necessary? Yes, you did say "any other..", but it would be more direct to just say what you want without reference to a regex.

Comment: All of the details in the comments need to be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try returning `captures` property of `match` method on regex `(\d+) ([\w ]+) at (\d+)`:

```
string.match(/(\d+) +(\D+) +at +(\d+)/).captures
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/Mgzjrz)

### Validating input string

If you didn't validate your input string to be within desired format already, then there may be a better approach in validating and capturing data. This solution also brings the idea of accepting any type of character in `item_name` field and decimal prices at the end:

```
string.match(/^(\d+) +(.*) +at +(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/).captures
```

Comment: `\D` is a bit weird matcher. `22 bottles of 7up at 20`?

Comment: I assume *item_name* couldn't have digits inside. Otherwise replacing `\D` with `[\w ]` will be enough.

Comment: `\w` obviously won’t work either.

Comment: Thanks again for saving me from a future issue :)

Comment: @revo: "What goes around comes around?" No, this isn't a symmetrical situation. I told you what the problem with your answer is. You only complained about another solution, which was actually more robust than yours. You didn't change anything, so I downvoted your answer. If you have constructive criticism, I'd be happy to hear it. But please don't downvote just for revenge.

Comment: *If you have constructive criticism...* I'd appreciate it if you had one. @EricDuminil

Comment: I didn't ***only*** complained about the other solution. I had absolutely some valid points. And not only me but two more people thought the same. @EricDuminil

Comment: Read this from OP: *I have a string* and be more precise about it. He didn't say *I've a string that **contains** or **may contain** a string like this...*. So appending `$` to regex is just an option and should be explained if someone did it. @EricDuminil

Comment: Don't remove your comments to not mess up others, please. @EricDuminil

Comment: I don't care about assumptions, I said already. *chocolate bar* is fine as an *item_**name*** but what the hell on earth a name could contain " at ".... I don't know really. You can ping original poster to clarify things. Don't think you are right when you are not. @EricDuminil

Comment: If it is possible then I can think of an invalid input string since ` at \d+` shouldn't be placed in a name field which has to be filtered. And yes, decimal pricing is common I never said it's not. @EricDuminil

Comment: It's up to original poster. I never noted weather or not it would be a case neither did he, that's why I didn't expand my answer to include it. If you like to be more than enough that's not bad and there is nothing wrong with it. @EricDuminil

Answer (score 4):

You could use `scan` with a regex:

```
"1 chocolate bar at 25".scan(/^(\d+) ([\w ]+) at (\d+)$/).first
```

The above method doesn't work if `item_name` has special characters.

If you want a more robust solution, you can use `split`:

```
number1, *words, at, number2 = "1 chocolate bar at 25".split
p [number1, words.join(' '), number2]
# ["1", "chocolate bar", "25"]
```

`number1` is the first part, `number2` is the last one, `at` the second to last, and `*words` is an array with everything in-between. `number2` is guaranteed to be the last word.

This method has the advantage of working even if there are numbers in the middle, `" at "` somewhere in the string or if prices are given as floats.

Comment: You thought it would be possible for * at * to be there in `item_name`. Okay, right. You also thought an `item_name` may contain `_` in it. (as per using `\w`) but the question is why didn't you think an apostrophe `'` (: *O'reilly* ), a comma `,` (: *MySQL, PHP book* ) or parentheses `()` (: *Server (Apache)* ) and many more special characters could be a part of a name?!

Comment: I know you have two different imaginations which conflict. I down-voted for the first. That was my constructive criticism.

Comment: Your second method also doesn't have anyway to apply `^` and `$` anchors on input string which you were arguing about that insistently under my post.

Comment: *`number2` will always be the last part of the string*... but second method doesn't ensure that `number2` will always contain a price! I remember you said *You need at least `$` or `\z` at the end of your regexp* because you had a reason! So you should apply your reason / idea on your own solutions as well.

Comment: Yes, *guaranteed to be the last word* but not the right chunk.

Comment: For sure, that's what I'm saying all the time, we don't know anything more than that! But I don't think you read my comments at all hence repeating nonsense over and over. You should tell me the reason why you were trying to convince me to append `$` or `\z` to the regex. If you know the reason you should know your second solution doesn't follow it. Simple English, isn't it? If you can't get the point then I'm not the culprit. That's enough for me the readers of these comments, if any actually, will understand what was going on. Period.

Comment: I don't like to continue. The one who began arguing were you not me. Your first method doesn't accept this `at x at 1.99 at` but the second does. You are suggesting two different problematic ways. You never explained differences between them and never noted their failing cases and their matching domain. You are only providing a temp solution to the problem. Wasted!

Comment: Don't kid yourself. I'm done at this point.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use a regular expression.

```
str = "1 chocolate bar, 3 donuts and a 7up at 25"

i1 = str.index(' ')
  #=> 1
i2 = str.rindex(' at ')
  #=> 35
[str[0,i1].to_i, str[i1+1..i2-1], str[i2+3..-1].to_i]
  #=> [1, "chocolate bar, 3 donuts and a 7up", 25]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
> s="1 chocolate bar at 25"
> s.scan(/[\d ]+|[[:alpha:] ]+/)
=> ["1 ", "chocolate bar at ", "25"]
```

Then to get the integers and the stripped string:

```
> s.scan(/[\d ]+|[[:alpha:] ]+/).map {|s| Integer(s) rescue s.strip}
=> [1, "chocolate bar at", 25]
```

And to remove the `" at"`:

```
> s.scan(/[\d ]+|[[:alpha:] ]+/).map {|s| Integer(s) rescue s[/.*(?=\s+at\s*)/]}
=> [1, "chocolate bar", 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
"1 chocolate bar at 25"
  .split()
  .reject {|string| string == "at" }
  .map {|string| string.scan(/^\D+$/).empty? ? string.to_i : string }
```

Code Example: http://ideone.com/s8OvlC

Comment: `split(' ')` is redundant, use `split` without arguments. Also, this answer is plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about split. Why in your opinion is it wrong? It works!

Comment: @dhaliman: Tried the snippet at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/I12tKF) and it works. Just a slight change to the regex. Not wrong at all. In fact, very correct.

Comment: @GregBurghardt you must be kidding. The expected result is `[1, "chocolate bar", 25]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Have a look at the ideone.com code example. That's exactly what it returns. I have a line commented out that shows the data type of each element in the resulting array.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I see what you mean. It includes the word "at".

Comment: @mudasobwa: I see clearly now. The expected result and the results from my code are not the same.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Are you sure this is correct? Can you suggest an edit since it doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: @dhaliman: Edited and corrected

Answer (score -1):

I live in the country where prices might be float, hence the more sophisticated matcher for the price.

```
"1 chocolate bar at 25".
  match(/\A(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+at\s+(\d[.\d]*)\z/).
  captures
#⇒ ["1", "chocolate bar", "25"]
```

Comment: Not right on *1 chocolate bar at .*

Comment: @revo indeed, fixed.

Comment: Why should it return third capture group as `5......` in *1 chocolate bar at 5......*?

Comment: @revo because `1 chocolate bar at 5......` is not a valid input as by OP?

Comment: So you mean you hadn't to edit your post after my first comment?

Comment: By considering a floating point number as *item_price* you are defining your own *valid input* not OP's. So do it right or don't at all.

Comment: "Most correct"? What isn't correct about my second method?

Comment: @EricDuminil indeed, your latter method is likely even better, I beg your pardon,

Comment: @revo: What if item_price isn't stored as a float? muda's answer works just fine. So what's the problem? For what it's worth, your answer isn't correct because you don't check the pattern matches the whole string.

Comment: @revo: And how did you get this information? The only thing that OP wrote is `The format of string will be "no_of_item item_name at price"`. There's no information at all about `item_name`, so you shouldn't assume anything about it, yet you did. That's why you got my downvote. What's *your* reason for downvoting me, expect childish retaliation?

Comment: @revo: Okay, you don't want to understand, so I'll just try one last time and then give up. "No information about `item_name`" means that it could be any string, with any character. Done.

Comment: @revo Because you lose one point when you downvote. Revenge and lies don't belong here. Please behave like a grown up on SO